# React typescript Element' is not assignable to type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
    import * as React from "react";

    import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
    import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";


    const isIndeterminate = indeterminate => indeterminate;
    const selectableRowsComponentProps = { indeterminate: isIndeterminate };


    class BarChart extends React.Component<any, any> {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {

            }
        }


    render() {
        const {
        columns,
        rec_columns,
        data
        } = this.state;
        
        return (
            <div className="cluster-menu style-2">
            <DataTable
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            defaultSortField="title"
            // sortIcon={<SortIcon />}
            pagination
            selectableRows
            selectableRowsComponent={Checkbox}
            selectableRowsComponentProps={{selectableRowsComponentProps}}
            />
        </div>
        );
    }
    }

    export default BarChart;
```

Here is my react code. I am using typescript

Below error i am getting.
The error is because `selectableRowsComponent={Checkbox}` line
In my vs code `checkbox` is showing red line

```
    ERROR in src/app/react-wrapper/BarChart.tsx(885,58): error TS2322: Type '(props: CheckboxProps) => Element' is not assignable to type '"input" | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
    Type '(props: CheckboxProps) => Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>': type, props, key
    src/app/react-wrapper/BarChart.tsx(898,49): error TS2322: Type '(props: CheckboxProps) => Element' is not assignable to type '"input" | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
    Type '(props: CheckboxProps) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
    src/app/react-wrapper/BarChart.tsx(910,49): error TS2322: Type '(props: CheckboxProps) => Element' is not assignable to type '"input" | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
    Type '(props: CheckboxProps) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
    src/app/react-wrapper/BarChart.tsx(958,49): error TS2322: Type '(props: CheckboxProps) => Element' is not assignable to type '"input" | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
    Type '(props: CheckboxProps) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
```

Above error i am getting.
The error is because `selectableRowsComponent={Checkbox}` line
In my vs code `checkbox` is showing red line

Please take a look what will be the issue.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `Checkbox` component and it's prop type?

Comment: based on the way the types are defined in the `react-data-table-component` package, it wants `selectableRowsComponent` to be an `Element` (the JSX returned from the component) rather than the component itself.  So you would want to do `selectableRowsComponent={<Checkbox/>}`.  However this seems at odds with the presence of the `selectableRowsComponentProps` prop, so much so that I wonder if there is a mistake in the package typings.

Comment: I'm looking at it more and it's definitely a mistake on their end rather than on yours.